# trouble with installation Symfony 2.2.*

Tags: symfony

I am trying to install symfony 2.2.* but it shows this error

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",

     "symfony/symfony": "2.2.*",
    "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "2.3.*@dev",
    "sonata-project/cache-bundle": "dev-master",
    "sonata-project/block-bundle": "2.2.*@dev",
    "sonata-project/jquery-bundle": "1.10.*@dev",
    "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle" : "2.3.*@dev",
    "sonata-project/core-bundle": "2.2.*",


    "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "1.2.*",
    "twig/extensions": "1.0.*",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "2.1.*",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "2.2.*",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "2.2.*",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "2.2.*",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "2.2.*",
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "2.3.*@dev",
```

this is the error appeared.
I guess it checks every versions in order, but finally it doesnt install anything.

I have changed versions many times, however it dosent' solved.

```
  Problem 1
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.2.11
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/class-loader v2.5.0
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.2.10
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.2.9
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/class-loader v2.5.0-RC1
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.2.8
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.2.7
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/class-loader v2.5.0-BETA2
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.2.6
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.2.5
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/class-loader v2.5.0-BETA1
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.2.4
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.2.3
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/class-loader v2.4.6
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.2.2
    - Installation request for adesigns/calendar-bundle dev-master -> satisfiable by adesigns/calendar-bundle[dev-master].
    - Installation request for sonata-project/admin-bundle 2.3.*@dev -> satisfiable by sonata-project/admin-bundle[2.3.x-dev].
    - sonata-project/admin-bundle 2.3.x-dev requires symfony/class-loader ~2.3 -> satisfiable by symfony/class-loader[v2.3.0, v2.3.1, v2.3.10, v2.3.11, v2.3.12, v2.3.13, v2.3.14, v2.3.15, v2.3.16, v2.3.2, v2.3.3, v2.3.4, v2.3.5, v2.3.6, v2.3.7, v2.3.8, v2.3.9, v2.4.0, v2.4.0-BETA1, v2.4.0-BETA2, v2.4.0-RC1, v2.4.1, v2.4.2, v2.4.3, v2.4.4, v2.4.5, v2.4.6, v2.5.0, v2.5.0-BETA1, v2.5.0-BETA2, v2.5.0-RC1].
    - don't install symfony/class-loader v2.3.0|don't install symfony/symfony v2.2.0
    - don't install symfony/class-loader v2.3.1|don't install symfony/symfony v2.2.0
    - don't install symfony/class-loader v2.3.10|don't install symfony/symfony v2.2.0
    - don't install symfony/class-loader v2.3.11|don't install symfony/symfony v2.2.0
    - don't install symfony/class-loader v2.3.12|don't install symfony/symfony v2.2.0
    - don't install symfony/class-loader v2.3.13|don't install symfony/symfony v2.2.0
    - don't install symfony/class-loader v2.3.14|don't install symfony/symfony v2.2.0
    - don't install symfony/class-loader v2.3.15|don't install symfony/symfony v2.2.0
    - don't install symfony/class-loader v2.3.16|don't install symfony/symfony v2.2.0
    - don't install symfony/class-loader v2.3.2|don't install symfony/symfony v2.2.0
    - don't install symfony/class-loader v2.3.3|don't install symfony/symfony v2.2.0
    - don't install symfony/class-loader v2.3.4|don't install symfony/symfony v2.2.0
    - don't install symfony/class-loader v2.3.5|don't install symfony/symfony v2.2.0
    - don't install symfony/class-loader v2.3.6|don't install symfony/symfony v2.2.0
    - don't install symfony/class-loader v2.3.7|don't install symfony/symfony v2.2.0
    - don't install symfony/class-loader v2.3.8|don't install symfony/symfony v2.2.0
    - don't install symfony/class-loader v2.3.9|don't install symfony/symfony v2.2.0
    - don't install symfony/class-loader v2.4.0|don't install symfony/symfony v2.2.0
    - don't install symfony/class-loader v2.4.0-BETA1|don't install symfony/symfony v2.2.0
    - don't install symfony/class-loader v2.4.0-BETA2|don't install symfony/symfony v2.2.0
    - don't install symfony/class-loader v2.4.0-RC1|don't install symfony/symfony v2.2.0
    - don't install symfony/class-loader v2.4.1|don't install symfony/symfony v2.2.0
    - don't install symfony/class-loader v2.4.2|don't install symfony/symfony v2.2.0
    - don't install symfony/class-loader v2.4.3|don't install symfony/symfony v2.2.0
    - don't install symfony/class-loader v2.4.4|don't install symfony/symfony v2.2.0
    - don't install symfony/class-loader v2.4.5|don't install symfony/symfony v2.2.0
    - adesigns/calendar-bundle dev-master requires symfony/symfony ~2.1 -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony[v2.2.0, v2.2.1, v2.2.10, v2.2.11, v2.2.2, v2.2.3, v2.2.4, v2.2.5, v2.2.6, v2.2.7, v2.2.8, v2.2.9].
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.2.1
```

Comment: It look like the issue is with your chosen version of `sonata-project/admin-bundle` requiring `symfony/class-loader` 2.3 but you are requiring `symfony/*` 2.2 and so are causing a conflict. It would make more sense to install 2.3 as (as @vpx has said) 2.2 is no longer supported while 2.3 is being supported until 05/2017.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem comes from sonata libraries. You try to install `"sonata-project/admin-bundle": "2.3.*@dev"` whereas this version is only compatible with Symfony >= 2.3 according to [packagist](https://packagist.org/packages/sonata-project/admin-bundle). The same goes for others sonata libraries.

So, you have two solutions:

- Downgrade sonata libraries to 2.2.* which is compatible with Symfony 2.2.*
- Upgrade Symfony to 2.3.* or higher

Basically, before requiring a library, you need to check on http://packagist.org if the version you specify is compatible with your others packages.

Comment: I downgraded "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "2.2.*", and      "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle" : "2.2.*", then the problem is solved thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

Symfony2.2.* not supported anymore.
http://symfony.com/roadmap?version=2.2

Try to change version description or follow the instructions

- http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html
- http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/2-2/doc/index.html

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I see, 2.2 is not supported anymore. For now I will keep use 2.2 though, I will update in near future